# ansible-galaxy install not working on RedHat 9

Tags: redhat, ansible, ansible-galaxy, rhel9

I am currently trying to install the community.general collection for ansible, which is fairly straight forward as I did it on countless systems including RedHat 8. But to my surprise, I tried install Redhat9 for the first time, and for some reason the command runs in an endless loop. it does not spur out some std_err output, just keeps going forever.

```
[root@localhost site]# ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
Starting galaxy collection install process
Process install dependency map
```

That's it, keeps going forever. I tried to debug but I have very little to go on. Anyone faced the same problem? I am certain it is not an internet issue, I have just installed many libraries/dependencies!

Thank you in advance.